# Is this injective(one to one): $ \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z^+}; g(x) = \lvert x\rvert + 1 $

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble figuring out the domain and co-domain for this question? So even though the domain is all integers be it positive or negatives, would the co-domain only allow for all positive integers? So instead of a V-shaped diagram, I would get a simple sloped line increasing in the positive x-direction.

Comment: Consider $g(x)$ and $g(-x)$.

Comment: the codomain $\mathbb Z^+$ is natural, since plugging any integer into $g$ yields a non-negative integer (and thus $g$ is surjective onto $\mathbb Z^+$). Regarding injectivity, simply consider $g(1)$ and $g(-1)$.

Comment: The y-intercept is non-negative, so actually you will still get the v-shape diagram where all outputs are in fact positive.

Comment: oh, so it's not one to one I was overthinking it a bit, since the codomain only applies to the output if the output is a positive integer it would have two x values with the same g(x) value!

Comment: In genral if $g(x)= f(x)+ a $, then the graph of $g(x)$ is the graph of $f(x)$ translated |a| units up or down. So the minimum value of $g$ is $1$ unit bigger than the minumun value of $f(x)=|x|$